# UISlider doesn't show in view

Tags: ios, uiview, uislider

I'm trying to create a UISlider in code, it's fairly simple what I'm doing:

```
self.slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(66.0, 15.0, 235.0, 23.0)];
self.slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
self.slider.maximumValue = 100.0;
self.slider.continuous = YES;

self.slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[self.view addSubview:self.slider];
```

That code goes in my `viewDidLoad` method and that's pretty much all I need, but the slider will not appear when my view is shown. Tried calling `setNeedsDisplay` on the view as well and it didn't work.

Comment: what is the frame dimensions on self.view?

Comment: What's in your class' .h file regarding that slider?

Comment: Nothing, the property is declared in an interface inside my .m file since i don't want it exposed: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *slider;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating your slider in code, then you shouldn't have an IBOutlet to it, and the declaration should be strong (it's probably being deallocated, since you only have a weak reference).

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)  UISlider *slider;
```